# Facebook Graph API: Have extended permission, need something odd

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

So, I have a FB app already, and when people connect I ask for the extended permission "email" and that is all well and good.  I save the email and can get a list of their friends' ids and basic profiles.

I want to know if there is a way for me to figure out which of their friends have allowed their email to be visible to people/friends/public (not my app) and then get that email so I can give back a list of people they can connect to.

So, let's say you have 12 on facebook, and of those 12, 4 have allowed anyone to see their email.  I want to give you those 4 emails because they have allowed them to be publicly/friend visible.  Other than those, I'd have to set up a custom "request permission to know your email" kind of thing.

It seems as though it's not possible, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Well indeed, I've just tested it myself and it seems the email address is indeed not disclosed, although I've just made it public for the sake of an experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't allow access to friend email addresses for obvious privacy reasons. You have to explicitly ask for this from each user.

Comment: I feel like there's been a misunderstanding, so I'll try to clarify the problem.  Person A and Person B are friends on facebook and have both connected to my app and have both given me their email address.  I want to know if Person A can see Person B's email while using facebook outside of the realm of my app.  This is because I want people who are friends on FB to be able to interact, and that is done with the email as the unique identifier.  If Person A can't already see Person B's email address normally I don't want to just give B's email to A even though I have both via the app.

Comment: That's an interesting use case, but there's currently no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll just have to figure something out to get it working but not trample all over privacy.